# How to log nginx requests made to a specific location in a different file?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx acting as a proxy in front of of a backend and I want to separate the requests made to a specific location to a separate file.

Still the requests should go to the same backend server but I don't want to see them inside the main access log.

Also I don't want to specify all the proxy_ stuff twice.

```
server {
    ...
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/jira.access.log full;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/jira.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 150m;        

    location /special/ {
        }

    location / {

            # many lines of config params for proxy_...
            proxy_pass   http://dowa-02.example.com:8080;
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**UPD**

Hmmm... `access_log` directive have a "feature".

[Requests are logged in a context of a location where processing ends. This may be different from the original location, if an internal redirect happens during request processing.](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

In case of `try_files` the internal redirect. Try change `try_files` to `include` & remove named location.

**END OF UPD**

---

In order not to repeat many times "proxy_ stuff", you can use [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive, for example. But [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) and named location are much better :)

```
server {
    ...
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/jira.access.log full;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/jira.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 150m;

    location /special/ {
        try_files $uri @backend;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/special.access.log full;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
            # many lines of config params for proxy_...
            proxy_pass   http://dowa-02.example.com:8080;
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was considering the same approach, implemented it did `service nginx reload`, nothing changed, did `nginx restart` nothing changed... the special log file is not created and the log is still full of /special/ requests...

Comment: Something very strange was happening with nginx, i needed to install it again as to make it work. Until I stopped it any command was "succesful" but in fact was doing nothing.

Comment: see update, please

Comment: Now the question is which is the final context? I would really like to used named locations as they seem to be the right way to keep the configuration easy to maintain. Now: nginx is creating the logs but it always using the access log which is specified at `server` level. Any workarounds without include?

Comment: only `include` is workaround. final context in original location instead of named - a feature of `access_log` directive.